# Bluetooth Low energy android app not working all the time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have refereed the below link to create android app.

1)https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-part-1/

2)https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-bluetooth-testbed/tree/a/android-ble-part-1

But the app is not working all the time.

Comment: Bluetooth devices will be connected but advertised data is not received by client.

Comment: Please read the help center before posting.

Answer (score 1):

you can go through this sample code to get data from ble devices

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHandler = new Handler();
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .build();
            filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
        }
        scanLeDevice(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        scanLeDevice(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mGatt == null) {
        return;
    }
    mGatt.close();
    mGatt = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Bluetooth not enabled.
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                } else {
                    mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                }
            }
        }, SCAN_PERIOD);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
        }
    }
}


private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.e("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
        Log.e("result", result.toString());//here you will get the details in ascii format and you have to convert that ascii to actual value
        BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
        connectToDevice(btDevice);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        for (ScanResult sr : results) {
            Log.e("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
    }
};

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                 byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.e("onLeScan", device.toString());
                        connectToDevice(device);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (mGatt == null) {
        mGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback);
        scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
    }
}

private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        Log.e("onConnectionStateChange", "Status: " + status);
        switch (newState) {
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                gatt.discoverServices();
                break;
            case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
        Log.e("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
        gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get
                (0));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                             characteristic, int status) {
        Log.e("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
        gatt.disconnect();
    }
};
```

and you have to add permission for bluetooth

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<usesfeature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: I have added all the permission to the code.But in my code the devices are connected but time stamp sent from the server device is not received by the Client device.
Please find my GitHub repository : https://Darshan017@bitbucket.org/Darshan017/ble.git

Comment: In onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) you will get the message.you can get the timestamp from result